# How to point to country by it's name?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Assuming that I don't know my current location, how to move `MapView` to country by it's name?

What I'm trying to do is display user's country by country code in locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a table in android with a link between country and geolocation that I'am aware of.

I believe the best approach is to get a list of all capital cities with latitude and longitude (you can get them here : [list of capital cities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_longitude)) or a list of countries (you can get them from here : [list of countries](http://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://www.newstrackindia.com/information/worldinfo/Latitude-and-Longitude-of-Countries.html&ei=Mm5pUOvsPMuThgeJlIDQCw&usg=AFQjCNGu4gM2Nx8PUYLTidqNn821QmBGbw)) and put it in a table in your application.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can display User's country by Country Code.

As we have facility to get the `CountryCode` through `Android Telephony Manager Api` so.

1)You have to use Key Value pairs concept, Key as `CountryCode` and Value as Country.

like the following code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

Comment: And then... ? I need to point to country at `MapView`, so how Country ISO can help?

Comment: you can check out the following link and use the CountryISO value to populate .....https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview